# Image mouse move coordinates it returns picture-edit coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, image, picturebox

I have a big image on pictureedit. Image size x=2027 y=851 and pictureedit size x=1320 y=806. I want find image coordinates used to mouse move, but mouse move return me pictureedit coordinates.

Comment: It seems like you just want to multiple the mouse coordinates by the scaling factor of the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Control.PointToScreen(Point)` and `Control.PointToClient(Point)` to switch between the global cordinate system and the local cordinate system.

Comment: It all depends on your requirement, can you put more details on what you want to do and some code example?